# Prove that if $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}=x$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}=x$

Tags: limits

Prove that if $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}=x$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}=x$

My proposed solution uses the following prepositions:

Proposition 4.7. Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that ${\sqrt[n]{a_n}}$ converges to L. If L < 1
the sequence converges to zero, if L > 1 the sequence is divergent, if L = 1 the test is inconclusive.
Proposition 4.8. Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges to L.

If L < 1 the sequence converges to zero, if L > 1 the sequence is divergent, if L = 1 the test is inconclusive.

These tests are perfectly equivalent and so their limits must be the same.

That is my solution but we were given the hint that we could use the result $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n^s}=x^s$ where s is rational and I have not used this hint which makes me think my solution is wrong. Also my solution seems too simple.

Comment: Your reasoning doesn't actually work. You haven't justified why the limits should be equal. What do you mean by the tests being equivalent?

Comment: It is quite possible that one test is inconclusive and the other is not. So $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ and $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}=x\neq 1$. Or it is possible that if $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n$ exists and $\lim\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ does not.

Comment: $a_n$ should be strictly positive then only the assertion is true.

Comment: Ok I was not confident that I was right but now I have no idea of the possible solution :/

Comment: I do not understand how the two terms are related

Comment: Is there a way you can force out $a_n$ from the $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ terms?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\limsup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \ge \limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n} \ge \liminf \sqrt[n]{a_n} \ge \liminf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, so if the first exists then so does the second.

Comment: Sure, but the above argument doesn't state that. I was pointing out why the argument made by the OP is wrong, not that the theorem is wrong. @r9m

Comment: I just realised this is actually a duplicate (oops) but thanks for your answers. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561076/is-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-a-n1-a-n-l-implies-lim-n-rightarrow-inft?rq=1

Comment: @babylon) Hello , my dear, Do you know how to accept the answer ? If an answer is helpfull to you then accept the answer first and then ask the next question..No answer is accepted by you of your question..

Answer (score 6):

Take the log of
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=x
$$
and rewrite it as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}{(n+1)-n}=\log(x)
$$
Then apply [the Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(a_n)}{n}=\log(x)
$$
Apply $e^x$ to get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\large n]{a_n}=x
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to x$ as $n\to\infty$ there exists a $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\left| {\frac{{{a_{n + 1}}}}{{{a_n}}} - x} \right| \le \varepsilon $ for all $n\ge n_0$. This leads to
$$\left( {x - \varepsilon } \right){a_n} \le {a_{n + 1}} \le \left( {x + \varepsilon } \right){a_n},\,\,\,\forall n \geqslant {n_0}.$$
By induction, we get
$${\left( {x - \varepsilon } \right)^{n - {n_0}}}{a_{{n_0}}} \leqslant {a_n} \leqslant {\left( {x + \varepsilon } \right)^{n - {n_0}}}{a_{{n_0}}},\,\,\,\,\forall n \geqslant {n_0}$$
$$\Rightarrow {\left( {x - \varepsilon } \right)^{\frac{{n - {n_0}}}
{n}}}{\left( {{a_{{n_0}}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \leqslant \sqrt[n]{{{a_n}}} \leqslant {\left( {x + \varepsilon } \right)^{\frac{{n - {n_0}}}{n}}}{\left( {{a_{{n_0}}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}},\,\,\,\,\forall n \geqslant {n_0}.$$
Let $n\to\infty$, we get
$$x - \varepsilon  \leqslant \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{{{a_n}}} \leqslant x + \varepsilon  \Rightarrow \left| {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{{{a_n}}} - x} \right| \leqslant \varepsilon .$$
So,
$$\left| {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{{{a_n}}} - x} \right| = 0$$
or
$${\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{{{a_n}}} = x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We need another theorem like the Stolz–Cesàro theorem in the other answer or the one here [If $\lim a_n = L$, then $\lim s_n = L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555365/if-lim-a-n-l-then-lim-s-n-l) that I will use here.

\begin{align}
&Let\space b_n = \ln{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \ln x\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n b_k}{n} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln a_{n+1}-\ln a_1}{n}=\ln x\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln a_{n}}{n}=\ln x\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{\ln a_{n}}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}= x
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint : try to prove that $$\forall k , \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{x^{n+1-k}a_k}=1$$ then use $k=0$ to conclude

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_n=\log a_n$. Then you know $\Delta b_n\to\log x$, hence $\frac 1 n\log a_n=\frac 1 n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\Delta b_i\to \log x$.